# MySQL Variables and referencing multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a database within MySQL that has a main table and some other tables that reference back to the main table. The idea is that I can give a user permission to edit one of the other tables and that would update the main table that they won't have access to.

For Example:

`table.main` includes *username,password,company,filepath,status* etc
`table.submain` includes *username,company,status*

I also would like to pass information from some of these columns to another column such as a file path.

For example: (Syntax is wrong)

```
Column File Path = srv/${company}/${username}/
```

I know I could do this with a BASH cron job but that seems a bit bodge and I know there must be a cleaner way of doing it within MySQL I just have little experience with it.

Just a point in the right direction, either query command or a link to some documentation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by 'passing information from some columns to another column'?  Copy info from one table to another?  Using which identifier?